# GNUPLOT through a python script gives damaged gif

Tags: python, gnuplot, fork

I am using the following script to run GNUPLOT on a redhat machine by forking. But what happens is that the image gets created, but is damaged, and hence I am not able to open it in a browser. 
Here is the script:

```
x=0
        dt=0.5  
        while isprocessrunning(pid_redis):
            result=commands.getstatusoutput("ps -p "+ pid_redis+" -o %cpu,%mem | tail -n 1");
            redis_file.write(str(x)+"\t"+result[1]+"\n")
            time.sleep(dt)
            x=x+dt;

        result=commands.getstatusoutput("gnuplot redis_mem.gpt")
```

Here is the redis_mem.gpt file:

```
 reset
 set autoscale
 set term gif
 set output './plots/REDIS_MEM_LOADTEST.gif'
 set title 'MEM_USAGE v/s. Time'
 set xlabel 'Time'
 set ylabel 'Mem_usage'
 plot 'redis_data.txt' u 1:3 smooth unique with lines
```

Also , I am running the above script by forking a child .
Where am I going wrong? Am i missing something in the .gpt file?

Comment: what happens if you `redis_file.flush()` before you use `result=commands.getstatusoutput("gnuplot redis_mem.gpt")`?

Comment: As another side note, `commands` is deprecated.  You could use `os.system` instead here, but `subprocess` is even better.

Comment: Is there any chance that the subprocess gets killed before it is done?  Or that `redis_data.txt` gets deleted?  And does it work when you run gnuplot manually?